# Macro Excel Consolidate Many Workbooks with Same Worksheet Name

Tags: vba, excel

I have scenario: Workbook1, Workbook2, Workbook3, and Workbook4. Each of these workbooks have a sheet name wsheet_a. I am putting my macro in master workbook named master_file and I wanted to consolidate the wsheet_a worksheets in each workbook to  mf_wsheet in master_file workbook starting at a specific row (e.g.row 2). And once I rerun the macro, it replace the the existing data in mf_wsheet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you written any code yet?  You will want to start with looping through all the workbooks to find the sheet.  something like.
`Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
For Each wb in Application.Workbooks
  For Each ws in wb.Worksheets
    If ws.name = "wsheet_a" Then
      'do what you need to do
    End If
  Next ws
Next wb
`

Answer (score 0):

Try this... (You will need to update the macro with the path to your workbooks)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Compile_Workbook_Data()

    Dim master_wkbk As Workbook: Set master_wkbk = ThisWorkbook
    Dim master_sht As Worksheet: Set master_sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mf_wsheet")
    Dim current_wkbk As Workbook
    Dim current_sht As Worksheet
    Dim wkbk_list(1 To 4) As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim last_row As Integer
    Dim last_col As Integer

    wkbk_list(1) = "Workbook1.xlsx"
    wkbk_list(2) = "Workbook2.xlsx"
    wkbk_list(3) = "Workbook3.xlsx"
    wkbk_list(4) = "Workbook4.xlsx"

    For x = 1 To UBound(wkbk_list)

        Set current_wkbk = Workbooks.Open("Full Path to File" & wkbk_list(x))
        Set current_sht = current_wkbk.Worksheets("wsheet_a")

        last_row = current_sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        last_col = current_sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

        current_sht.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(last_row, last_col)).Copy

        last_row = master_sht.Cells.Find("*", searchorder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        master_sht.Range("A" & last_row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        current_wkbk.Close False

    Next x

End Sub
```